# I would like a book that is about functions that are being equal up to order ν at α

Tags: calculus, book-recommendation

Two functions $f, g$ are said to be equal up to order $\nu$ at $\alpha$ if and only if

$\lim_\limits{x→\alpha} \dfrac{f(x)−g(x)}{(x−\alpha)^\nu}=0$

I would like to research this property (*theorems for this*, *theorems from this*, *usages* etc). **Is there any book related to this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Excuse me, is it peraphs $x\to\alpha$ and not $x\to a$?

Comment: @Sebastiano , yes. My mistake...